# Magento 2.4.6: How to cancel orders partially via admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, extensions, magento2.4.6, cancel-orders

I want to cancel the order partially but there is no built-in feature for this in Magento 2. I have found out few extensions but those only have provision to cancel it via frontend but I need to cancel it via admin. Below are a few extensions but there is no option to cancel it via admin. Please suggest.

- https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-cancel-order-by-customers-extension.html
- https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-frontend-cancel-order-extension.html
- https://amasty.com/cancel-orders-for-magento-2.html

Any help will be appreciated.